# How to get all childs+grandchilds of a specific parent using Realm in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a 3 databases setup like this Parent->Child->Grandchild, so far I could manage to get the child of a specific parent, but couldn't go deeper to another level.

```
class Parent : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    let childs = List<Child>()
}

class Child : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    let grandchilds = List<Grandchild>()
    var giveBirth = LinkingObjects(fromType: Parent.self, property: "childs")
}

class Grandchild : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var giveBirth = LinkingObjects(fromType: Child.self, property: "grandchilds")
}
```

I used this line to count childs:

```
if let parent = itemsFromParentList?[indexPath.row] {    
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(parent.childs.count)"
}
```

But I want to get the total of all childs+grandchilds of a specific parent, like "How many childs and grandchilds do you have?".

Many thanks!!!

Comment: I expect 6. All child levels that come from the first parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the plural of "child" is "children"

If I understood correctly, you need to flat map the parent's grandchildren, and then count it, then add the children count to it.

```
let childrenPlusGrandchildrenCount = parent.childs.flatMap { $0.grandchilds }.count + parent.childs.count
```

Comment: Mr. Sweeper, could I ask you for another question? What if I want to count the all the incurred childs level as well (let's say I have 5 levels (or more) of databases like parent-> child -> grandchild -> grand-grandchild -> grand-grand-grandchild -> ... ) how could I do that? I'm sorry, I know this's is a bit too much, but I'm not quite an expert yet, I tried to dig deeper into the solution you gave me but I was stuck again. Is there any solution that avoiding hard-coding?